# Wait and Notify in Game Sound context

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I have made a simple snake game in which I have implemented sound effects and some background music.

I've created a "soundFX" class to handle sounds, two instances of SoundFX play the gameOver and appleGet FX, but the soundFX class also extends thread in order to loop the background music as the game plays.

I want this music to stop when the player hits "game over" and then start back up with the game again once the player hits the space key.

I'm trying to use wait and notify to avoid busy-waiting the background-music-thread.

However, I cannot figure out how to do this without either perpetually leaving my background-music-thread in a waiting state, or hitting a "Thread is not current owner" exception.

I'm quite new to threads and despite youtube tutorials and reading in "Head First Java" I cannot figure out how to apply this to this context.

```
public class SoundFX extends Thread{

private final String soundName;
private volatile boolean isOn;
private volatile boolean isFailedGame = false;

public SoundFX(String soundName) {
    this.soundName = soundName;
}
public SoundFX(String soundName, boolean isOn) {
    this.soundName = soundName;
    this.isOn = isOn;
}

public void setOn(boolean on) {
    isOn = on;
}

public void setFailedGame(boolean failed){
    isFailedGame = failed;
}

public void playSound(String soundName){
    File soundFile = new File(soundName);
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile));
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    File soundFile = new File(soundName);
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile));
        while (Thread.currentThread().isAlive()) {
            if (!isOn) {
                clip.stop();
                if(isFailedGame) {
                    clip.setFramePosition(0);
                }
                //Thread.onSpinWait();
                this.wait();
            }
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

//region SoundFX
private String appleGetSound = "/Users/Niklas/Downloads/JavaFontysICT-master/2D-Snake-AwaisMirzaTutorial/AppleGet.wav";
private String failSound = "/Users/Niklas/Downloads/JavaFontysICT-master/2D-Snake-AwaisMirzaTutorial/SnakeFail.wav";
private String backgroundSong = "/Users/Niklas/Downloads/JavaFontysICT-master/2D-Snake-AwaisMirzaTutorial/SnakeSongLoop.wav";
SoundFX appleGetSoundFX = new SoundFX(appleGetSound);
SoundFX failedSoundFX = new SoundFX(failSound);
SoundFX backgroundSongLoop = new SoundFX(backgroundSong, false);
//endregion

private boolean paused = false;
private boolean failed = false;


public Gameplay() {
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);


    //the speed of the snake
    timer = new Timer(clockSpeed, this);
    backgroundSongLoop.start();
    timer.start();
}

public synchronized void paint(Graphics g){

    //region Default position
    if(moves==0){
        backgroundSongLoop.setOn(true);
        snakeXLength[2] = 50;
        snakeXLength[1] = 75;
        snakeXLength[0] = 100;

        snakeYLength[2] = 100;
        snakeYLength[1] = 100;
        snakeYLength[0] = 100;
        failed=false;
    }
    //endregion


    //region Snake-Snake Collision
    for (int b=1; b<lengthOfSnake; b++){
        if(snakeXLength[b]==snakeXLength[0] && snakeYLength[b]==snakeYLength[0]){
            backgroundSongLoop.setOn(false);
            backgroundSongLoop.setFailedGame(true);

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

            failedSoundFX.playSound(failSound);
            failed=true;
            timer.stop();

            //region High score manager
            if (score>highscores[2] && score<highscores[1]){
                highscores[2]=score;
            }
            if (score>highscores[1] && score<highscores[0]){
                highscores[2]=highscores[1];
                highscores[1]=score;
            }
            if (score > highscores[0]){
                highscores[2]=highscores[1];
                highscores[1]=highscores[0];
                highscores[0] = score;
            }
            //endregion

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(25, 75, 850, 575);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            g.drawString("GAME OVER", 300, 300);
            g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            g.drawString("Press [Space Bar] to play again", 300, 340);
            g.drawString("HIGHSCORES:", 380, 380);
            g.drawString("#1: " + highscores[0], 380, 400);
            if (highscores[1]>0){
                g.drawString("#2: " + highscores[1], 380, 420);
            }
            if (highscores[2]>0) {
                g.drawString("#3: " + highscores[2], 380, 440);
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion

    g.dispose();

}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    
    //region restart function
    if (failed){
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            backgroundSongLoop.setOn(true);
            backgroundSongLoop.setFailedGame(false);
            score = 0;
            lengthOfSnake = 3;
            moves = 0;
            repaint();
            timer.start();
        }
    }
    //endregion

    // region pause function
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && !paused && !failed){
        backgroundSongLoop.setOn(false);
        paused=true;
    } else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && paused && !failed){
        paused=false;
        backgroundSongLoop.setOn(true);
        timer.start();
    }
    //endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I recommend dropping the `Thread` extension from `SoundFX`. Simply make a `Clip` instance variable in your `SoundFX` class. Make separate methods for initializing (constructor works fine for this), playing and stopping playback of the clip. The play method (for continuous looping) would be the following:

```
public void play() {
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}
```

The `setFramePosition(0)` method is not strictly needed. It's there to ensure that if you stop your clip and wish to resume playback, the playback starts from the beginning of the sound.

When you instantiate your clip in the constructor, I recommend using a string that allows you to obtain a `URL` via the `getResource` method, and use the `URL` to make your `AudioInputStream`. It will save you from multiple headaches when it comes time to jar your program.

There is no need to combine the *opening* of a sound file with *starting* it. The `Clip` was actually designed for being initialize and opened and held in memory until the moment when playback is needed. It was also designed to allow stopping, repositioning and restarting. If an audio file is too large to hold in memory, a `SourceDataLine` is generally preferred to a `Clip`.